# How can I provide the application to iOS users in a country where the store (apple services) does not work?

Tags: ios, app-store

I found several services that allow you to distribute applications to users(ios).

[diawi](https://diawi.com)

[appsonair](https://appsonair.com/)

[deployninja](http://www.deployninja.com/)

[unicornlab](https://www.unicornlab.com/)

but I think they all use Apple services in their work.
this is from the documentation Diawi:

```
"How wireless app installation works on iOS
Over-the-air installation of apps on iOS is based on tools and features provided officially by 
Apple: itms-service and a valid manifest file providing information on the app."
```

but if apple services do not work in this country - how can I install the application? or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to enroll in Apple Developer Enterprise Program. It is like buying an Enterprise account. https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/
2. Create a Distribution certificate + Inhouse profile (or provisioning file). Inhouse distribution won't require the device's UUID. So any user can install it like download form AppStore.
   ref: https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009409294-How-to-create-In-House-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile
3. You can use Diawi, Testfairy,... to upload your exported *.ipa on it then share the link to users.